# Use Photoswipe with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, photoswipe

I am having a problem with [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) and Angular. Basically what I'm doing is get the images from my server using `$http.post` and then pushing those objects into my array of images, then I'm initializing Photoswipe.

In my success I have something like this:

```
$scope.gallery.push(images from server);
myPhotoSwipe.initialize()
```

But I get this error: `Code.PhotoSwipe.createInstance: No images to passed`, so the initialize is getting fired before all my items are in the view.

I can see all the images in my view but of course they are not attach to Photoswipe, any idea of how can I initialize it only after all my images are in the view?

PS: I have already tried this: [How can I get directive to fire after view loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528482/how-can-i-get-directive-to-fire-after-view-loaded/) but it didn't work for me

Thanks!