# Fire AngularJS directive on view load

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, reload

I have a rather simple app. In this case, the user click a button on home.html to go to map.html. On map.html, a jQuery plugin (made into a directive) should fire when that view loads. Currently it does not. It fire immediately when the app loads (home.html) even though the directive is not called until the user reaches map.html.

I also tried using [Angular UI.Utils (jQuery Passthrough)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq) but to no avail.

Here's my **directive**:

```
directive('tfinderMap', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).tfindermap(scope.$eval(attrs.tfinderMap));
       }
   };
});
```

jQuery plugin would simply be `$(element).tfinderMap({queryLimit: 3})` and that plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder/blob/master/app/js/map.js) - it's a Google Map API plugin I created.

My **controller** is empty at this point...

```
.controller('MapCtrl', [function() {
}])
```

My **map.html view** is basic as well...

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map" class="google-map-canvas" tfinder-map="{queryLimit: 3}"></div>

    <ul class="table-view" id="location-data">
        <!--plugin results get put into here-->
    </ul>

</div>
```

And my **index.html** loads all my scripts (Angular files & plugin code) and you can click on the nav item to go to map.html which is routed via `$routeProvider` (project was started with [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), FYI)

---

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528482/how-can-i-get-directive-to-fire-after-view-loaded) but I don't think the answers provided pertain to my issue.

So is there a way to just reload the entire page when I navigate to map.html, so then my directive will fire because the scripts will be reloading as well? Or is there a way to re-initialize the map.html view and scripts (or directive)?

As I mentioned above, I've tried using jQuery Passthrough as well as a `$scope.reload()` with no luck...

Lastly I'll mention if I do a manual browser refresh, my directive fires just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try firing the directive once the `tfinderMap` attribute is assigned:

```
attrs.$observe("tfinderMap",function(value){
 if(value){
   $(element).tfindermap(scope.$eval(attrs.tfinderMap));
 }
})
```

or alternatively a timeout with no wait:

```
$timeout(function(){
        $(element).tfindermap(scope.$eval(attrs.tfinderMap));
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! This has been driving me insane. I ended up using the first example you provided. But I also tested the second and it worked too.